# Google Optimize installation on AMP page: Not verified

Tags: google-optimize, amp-analytics

We are trying to implement the amp-experiments on the amp-page and connect it with Google Optimize. We follow the instruction in this article — [Measure AMP experiments with Optimize](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/amp-experiments). But there is nothing about how to and should we to integrate Google optimize script inside amp-page.

As a result, we run an experiment with that message:

[image]

Is it ok for the experiments on amp pages? We can't add that script to amp page — `<script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=...`, and we can't insert Google optimize via GTM — there is no way to do that in AMP GTM container

We did all as described in [Measure AMP experiments with Optimize](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/amp-experiments) article, but it doesn't work — we don't see any active users or sessions in Google optimize dashboard

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?